# Detecting errors in apc

Tags: php, apc

The php documentation describes how functions like apc_store return false if there is an error:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-store.php

I'm curious what it means when there is an error, as I can't find any functions to actually return what the error was, or any documentation on why it would fail and return false.

Is there an equivalent to php's error_get_last for these apc return false functions?  Or perhaps is error_get_last exactly what I'm looking for?

Thanks

Edit: actually the documentation says returns false on "failure", although I'm equally not sure what that means

Comment: Have you tried `error_get_last()`?

Comment: I'd recommend as a tangant, moving to ZendOpcache ASAP

Comment: @Ray Any reason in particular?

Comment: Maybe there was not enough memory left in the cache for the object trying to be stored?

Comment: @Jasper It's rolled into php 5.5 and support around APC is starting to fade a bit. https://www.activecollab.com/blog/3-zend-opcache-memcached.html

Comment: @Jasper Also, as a past addict and recovering apc user cache user, learn to love and use memcache, don't use the apc user cache :) .

Comment: @Ray I've used Wincache thus far, its installation was really simple, the integration was also simple, and the performance increase was amazing. But of course, that's just for Windows-based servers.

Comment: @Jasper yes, while I can't speak to non-linux/bsd options, that option sounds equally good.  Just in general use APC or ZendOpcache for op-code caching.

Comment: @Jasper I have not tried that error_get_last function, I dont actually have any errors in apc, I just want to be able to log them should one occur

Comment: @Ray if there's bugs in apcu, report them ...

Comment: @JoeWatkins There are no specific bugs that I'm aware of, but it's not the best choice for user-cache.  APCu lacks things like auto cache invalidation / swapping out less used content, it suffers from serious fragmentation issues requiring much higher memory alocatation than actually used for caching to avoid performance hits, etc...  I'd don't mind APC if for opcode caching, but with way PHP is moving with ZendOpcache, APC will probably got the way of the Dodo bird.  I used it happily for op caching until migrating to php 5.4, when I learned in 5.5 ZendOpcache is being rolled in.

Comment: The allocator is a perfectly standard allocator, it's probably the case that the extreme fragmentation you speak of is actually _due_ to APC being both opcode and user cache; the opcode and user cache shared the same allocator, competing for locks and using the same regions/segments. That would be my first, pretty well educated, guess. You know, you have some good ideas there ... it was complicated to change APC, it is not complicated to change APCu, if you can organize your thoughts into a proposal, I'll happily listen, if you can imagine it, I can write it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following conditions can cause apc_store to return false:

- APC is disabled by configuration directive
- Writing to the cache fails

Writing to the cache can fail for the following reasons:

- Shared memory is exhausted and or the SMA is busy (in garbage collection)
- The key is being defended from slamming - you have set that key in the previous second from another process or thread

APC does not set any global error numbers or strings upon failure, except, indirectly in those cases where the failure is due to an underlying syscall; don't rely on that.